# How do Range-Based for loops handle temporary containers

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume this example:

```
vector<int> get_vector();
for(auto& v: get_vector())
{
 ...
}
```

Is `get_vector()` re-evaluated on each iteration? Or a temporary is stored and evaluated once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_vector()` is evaluated once, and the result is stored in a temporary.

> **6.5.4/1** ...a range-based for statement is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>   auto && __range = range-init;
>   for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
>              __end = end-expr;
>        __begin != __end;
>        ++__begin ) {
>     for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>     statement
>   }
> }
> ```

In your example, `range-init` would be `(get_vector())`.

Comment: Thanks Igor. Where is this snipet from? the standard?

Comment: Yes, the C++ standard. **6.5.4/1** is the section and paragraph number (sometimes referred to as "chapter and verse").

Comment: Yes, I'd like to start learning How to fish :)

Comment: Important to note that the temporary is lifetime-extended by binding to a reference (`auto && __range`).